# Drawing horizontal line through center of page

Tags: formatting, rules

Is it possible to draw a horizontal line through the center of the page (such as with \hrule) regardless of the content of a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code could be a way...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw (current page.west) -- (current page.east);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, the `positioning` library is not needed for that. :)